# SharePoint 2010 Update Panel not working with Visual WebPart

Tags: 2010

i am developing a Visual Webpart and on user control i have DropDownList with autopostback is true and a gridview control. on selectedindexchange of dropdown i am filling my gridview if i put update panel around dropdownlist and change the item nothing happens and also no error when i remove update panel it works fine..whats the problem

Comment: I would refactor the solution to avoid "update panel" if possible. A clean webmethod  /service called through ajax will give you way much control and less trouble !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh well in my web.config the 3.5 assemblies were missing so i googled and got the solution.

1. Opened empty web application project.
2. Copy portal's web.config file to the project and set the target framework to 2.0
3. then select target framework 3.5 and save the file..

thats it..visual studio automatically added required entries in web.config..

Answer (score 0):

you should create a update panel in your createchildcontrols method and then add your user control in update panel using content template control or something can't remember properly as I did it few months back, and then add your update panel to CONTROLS.

Hope it helps, if you still didn't get by what I said then let me know I will add code for you :) !

Comment: TimeToShine..thanks..I tried but it didnt work. I would appreciate your sample code if possible

Comment: Another problem is <ScriptManager> do i need to add ajaxtoolkit scriptmanager? I have on scriptmanager exist in master page.